# Creating a class,for a box. (Java)

Tags: java, class

Hi I had this assignment for my class:

1. Implement a class named Box that will have the following attributes and methods:
   int length, width, height
   String color
2. Constructor method that:

   - will initialize the 3 integers to 10, 8, 6
   - will initialize the color to “black”
3. A setter and getter method for each of the 4 attributes
4. A method to get the volume of the box
5. A method to get the surface area of the box (all six sides)

I have all my getters and setters for length width and color. My only problem now is that for volume it will not calculate properly if I set the values to be different.

It only takes the initialized values. Any Ideas to go about it? My code is below for the class. example I could .setLength(7) and instead of printing the total 7*8*6, it prints out the total of 10*8*6.

```
    public class Box
    {
      private int height = 6;

      public void se(int height){
      this.height=height;
     } 
      public int getHeight(){
         return height;
     } 
    private int width = 8;
    public void setWidth(int width){
      this.width=width;
    } 
      public int getWidth(){
         return width;
    } 
    private int length= 10;
    public void setLength(int length){
      this.length=length;
    } 
      public int getLength(){
         return length;
    }
     private String color="Black";
     public void setColor(String color){
      this.color=color;
    } 
     public String getColor(){
      return color;
    }
    private int vol=length*width*height;
      public void setVol(int vol){
      this.vol=vol;

    }
    public int getVol(){
       return vol;
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the `vol` property and the `setVol` setter; that's not part of the spec for the class and is the root cause of your problems. Rewrite `getVol` to compute the volume from the length, width, and height each time it is called.

Your current design doesn't work because `vol` is not recalculated whenever `length`, `width`, or `height` is changed. You could keep your current set of fields and rewrite the dimension setters to recalculate the `vol` property each time one is called. That would speed up the `getVol` getter method at the cost of greater complexity for the class design and slower setter methods. It's a trade-off that you can make or not, as you see fit. However, you need to get rid of the `setVol` method, because when you set the volume, there's no way to know how to set the dimensions so that the values are consistent.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response! I have the correct results now! Now the surface area will be no problem!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `getter` function for `vol`

e.g.

```
public int getVol () {
   vol=length*width*height;
   return vol;
}
```

of course the setting of the intermediate `vol` is not necessary.
and you could just

```
return length*width*height;
```

This ensure that the current `vol` is always correctly calculated.